# How can I save a StorageFile to use later?

Tags: permissions, windows-8, windows-runtime, storage

I am working in WinRT, and I am kind of stuck:

I am writing a music player with a media library capability. I keep information about the music (such as artists etc) in a SQLite database. I wanted to let the user keep his music anywhere he wants to, instead of the windows way, where it all has to be in the 'Music' library.

Users can add the music inside folders using a folder picker. The problem I have is this: how can I access these files later, e.g after the application restarts?

Keeping the path doesn't work, since I always get "Access Denied" errors. The only time I can access the files is using the StorageFile objects I get from browsing the folder.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: So you're trying to bypass the limitations of an Individual account?

Comment: No, the question was about accessing a file/folder picked using the file picker later (e.g. after application is closed). The path/uri of the file is not enough, you will get a permission denied error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the comments already given, the Windows.Storage.AccessCache (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230566.aspx) is the API you need to use for this. However, instead of saving access to each individual StorageFile, use the folder picker and save permissions for the StorageFolder object instead (the API works for both). It's unlikely that you'll hit the 1000 item limit for folders.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Runtime apps are sandboxed. If you want to access arbitrary folder locations, you *have* to use the file picker.

Comment: This would work the first time a user selects the file. But how can I save that permission to access that file? When I add it to the library, I need to be able to access it later.

Comment: I haven't tried this personally, but maybe you can use the most recently used (MRU) list. See this link for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh972603.aspx

Comment: The link above also mentions a "future" access list, which sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the link. Unfortunately... "The futureAccessList can hold up to 1000 items." My music collection is around 3000 songs, so this limit won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

to access files in future

```
        string key = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(storageFile);
        //save this key for access file later

        //Access file from saved key
        StorageFile file = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(key);
```

if you have too much file you can add StorageFolder of files

```
        string key = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(storageFolder);
        StorageFolder folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(key);
```

then get StorageFiles from the parent StorageFolder

```
StorageFile childFile = await folder.GetFileAsync("filename");
```