# Best place for saving user data for Windows Store App

Tags: storage, windows-store-apps

Disclaimer: I am new to Windows Store App development.

My app is a Windows Store App (for desktop). The app has to create some content using user's input and the data can be considered as documents. Also, the document'd be in a proprietary format. The user should be able to see all those documents listed inside the app every time he launches it.

My question is where to save these document files. I have no issue it is directly accessible to users without using app (it is their data).

The document suggest roaming (limited storage) and local storage. But both are deleted once the app is deleted (bad for the user).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx

Document also states that accessing right for My Document folder is granted only if the developer is a company (bad for me).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx

Any other popular pattern from developers (apart from Azure, SkyDrive and any online storage)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On app's first launch, you can allow the user to choose his/her folder as per choice, and then add that folder in future access list. So you can access that folder anytime. Please check below given links.

[How can I save a StorageFile to use later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518649/how-can-i-save-a-storagefile-to-use-later)

[Exploring WinRT: Storage.AccessCache](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2011/10/10/winrt-storage-accesscache/)

[Windows.Storage.AccessCache Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230566.aspx)

Comment: Sounds a logical idea, but I don't want to bother users with unnecessary details, specially as it is very unlikely they'd access the data without using my app as they are in my proprietary format. I'll keep this option open as well though.