# How to create a folder in local drives through c# in winrt app

Tags: c#, windows-8

Can any one tell me how I can create a folder in local drives through c# code in winrt. I am creating a windows 8 app. I have to create a folder in local drives like in d drive or e drive through my winrt app to save some data in it. I don't want to create folder in local storage.

Can anyone tell me how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

WinRT restricts the filesystem locations that are available to applications.

See this detailed post for additional information: [Accessing data and files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464959.aspx)

Short answer: WinRT restricts the locations that your app can access, and it may not be possible to do what you want.

However, if you are saving data related to your application, what are the reasons for not using local app data?

Comment: I have to create a database backup in local drives that is already in local storage.If I save the backup in local storage then how user will get to use that backup in his app.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to access file system locations that the app does not have access to. The FileOpenPicker or FolderPicker. Once a user has selected the file and folder for the backup, you can maintain this access for future use by using the `Windows.Storage.AccessCache` namespace and the appropriate methods. Here is a link to the related answer: [Save File or Folder For Later Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518649/how-can-i-save-a-storagefile-to-use-later) .

Best of Luck